# Access denied to SQS via AWS SDK

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

I'm currently working on a website developed with Symfony2 and I need to send messages in an Amazon SQS. In order to do that I added to my `composer.json`:

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "2.4.*"
```

Then when I try to create a queue or list queues I've got a 403 error saying:

> Access to the resource https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ is denied.

**EDIT:**
added the full error message

> AWS Error Code: AccessDenied, Status Code: 403, AWS Request ID:
>   2fe34c11-7af8-5445-a768-070159a0953e, AWS Error Type: client, AWS
>   Error Message: Access to the resource
>   https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ is denied., User-Agent:
>   aws-sdk-php2/2.4.11 Guzzle/3.7.4 curl/7.25.0 PHP/5.4.3

Here is a sample code of what I do:

```
$aws = Aws::factory(array(
  'key'    => 'my-key',
  'secret' => 'my-secret',
  'region' => 'us-west-2'
));

$sqs = $aws->get('sqs');

return new Response(var_dump($sqs->listQueues()));
```

What do I do wrong to get this error ?

Comment: I ensured that it wasn't a proxy problem by adding curl options into the config array.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

After digging I discovered that the account I was using wasn't granted the access to SQS service.

To give a SQS access to an account you have to go to the amazon management console. Then click on IAM. Under this section click on Users and then you can manage permission for each account you created.

Comment: BINGO!! I was having the same issue with Access Rights to users
Thanks Supa

Comment: When every other services can be connected with default user, why there would be a separate need for SQS user?

Comment: BTW, what is the policy you attached? The following is not working and still shows 403.`{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sqs:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: In case you are facing this because of cloud formation. Try updating the permissions of sqs queue in my permission tab. Worked for me

Comment: Hi, sometimes is not the real solution, in my case i have granted all required permissions but finally the problem was relation to the mapping template in the Integration Request and also the header content type

Answer (score 15):

Make sure that both the following policies allow access to the SQS queue

1. **Resource (SQS) based policy**: The SQS queue should allow your identity to use the queue. You define this using the queue policy (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html#scenario-sqs-policy). The default queue policy will allow access only to the owner of the queue (owner of the queue is the identity that created the queue).
2. **Identity based policies**: The policy for the identity that is accessing the queue should have permission to invoke operations on the queue.

Make sure that the access is not restricted by either one of them.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-using-identity-based-policies.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same strange issue, I had everything set up including policies and permission, after a couple of hrs I found out I was getting 403 error because of wrong aws region was configured in my application it was supposed to be `ap-south-1` by default it was `us-east-1`